# Why does this function have three sections when it's declared?

Tags: go, functional-programming

I am trying to understand how to test AWS calls in golang and cannot understand whats happening with this function.

```
func (m mockedReceiveMsgs) ReceiveMessageRequest(in *sqs.ReceiveMessageInput) sqs.ReceiveMessageRequest {
    // Only need to return mocked response output
    return sqs.ReceiveMessageRequest{
        Request: &aws.Request{
            Data:        &m.Resp,
            HTTPRequest: &http.Request{},
            Retryer:     aws.NoOpRetryer{},
        },
    }
}
```

I understand it is a function called RecieveMessageRequest that takes a pointer to a RecieveMessage int and outputs a RecieveMessageRequest

But what is this section called?
`(m mockedReceiveMsgs)`

I don't understand why it is not passed as a normal parameter.

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations: *"The receiver is specified via an **extra parameter section preceding the method name**. That parameter section must declare a single non-variadic parameter, the receiver."*

Comment: Please at least complete the Tour of Go. It doesn't take long, and covers all the language fundamentals, [including this one](https://tour.golang.org/methods/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReceiveMessageRequest` is a method of the type `mockedReceiveMsgs`, and `m` is the receiver. If you have a variable `x` of type `mockedReceiveMsgs`, then you can call this as `x.ReceiveMessageRequest(arg)`, and the `m` in the method body will be a copy of `x`.

Answer (score -2):

You should read about `struct` [here](https://tour.golang.org/methods/1).

`(m mockedReceiveMsgs)` that means ReceiveMessageRequest is a method of mockedReceiveMsgs struct.

You can understand the same in OOP, method of class